# HackerRank staircase C confusion

Tags: c

Hi i'm pretty new and trying to improve through hackerrank, i am on the staircase excercise [staircase excercise](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/staircase)

However my output is different to the question, as it seems my staircase has a extra space infront of the result thus making it incorrect. here is my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () 
{

int size = 0;

//input size of staircase
scanf("%d" , &size);


//create array to hold staircase
char list [size];
//iterate through and fill up array with spaces
for (int i = 0; i <size; ++i)
{
    list[i] = ' ';
}
//the iterate backwards -1 each time replacing each spcae with a '#' and printing each stair case starting from smallest at the top.
for (int i = size; i >0; i--)
{
    list[i] = '#';
    printf("%s\n", list);
}


return 0;
}
```

I am confused as to what the problem is and why there is my staircase more spaced out than the expected question? i've been trying to work it out, and any help is really much needed.

My output:

```
      #
     ##
    ###
   ####
  #####
 ######
```

*EDIT - thanks for the help, all the answers were helpful.

Comment: 1) `i = size`.. `list[i] = '#';` occurs write to out-of-bounds.

Comment: Your first problem is that your using `printf` to print `list` as if it were a string, which it's not. Strings have terminating `'\0'` characters after the text characters, and have to be allocated large enough to accommodate them. And, your very first write to the `list` array is out of bounds.

Comment: fix like [this](http://ideone.com/2viFs4)

Comment: Can i ask more information on why strings require '\0' at the end needed, and what are the consequences of not using it?

Comment: `%s` of `printf("%s\n", list);` assumes that the string is terminated with 0(`'\0'`). If not, a read will be done beyond the expected location. However, in this case, if you understand that the string is not terminated by 0, it does not necessarily have to be NUL terminated. For example, you can do as follows. `printf("%.*s\n", size, list);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several mistakes:

1) You forgot to put a null character (`'\0'`) at the end of the string. Do this:

```
for (int i = 0; i <size; ++i)
{
    list[i] = ' ';
}
list[i] ='\0';
```

2)

```
for (int i = size; i >0; i--)
{
    list[i] = '#';
    printf("%s\n", list);
}
```

Here the index you are trying to access for the string is invalid (when i=size). Do like this:

```
for (int i = size-1; i > -1; i--)
{
    list[i] = '#';
    printf("%s\n", list);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An array of length `size` is indexed from `0` to `size - 1`:

E.g. for `size == 4`:

```
[0][1][2][3]
```

In your second loop you go from `size` to `1`, first writing *outside* the array, and finally leaving the first entry untouched:

```
[ ][#][#][#] #
```

You must either change your second loop to

```
for (int i = size - 1; i >= 0; i--)
```

or alternatively do

```
list[i - 1] = '#';
```

instead of `list[i] = '#'`.

Comment: He also needs to allocate an extra byte and put a zero at the end, or else `printf` won't know to stop (which it's apparently doing anyway, randomly--looks like he got luck and found a zero on that byte).

Comment: You seem to be right, but I didn't think that far :)